# How to print the most recent Cloudwatch log for a certain Lambda function from the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to use the AWS CLI and ASK CLI to code an Alexa skill, and I would like to be able to use the Alexa simulator and view the console logs directly from the command line to make it easy, but I am not sure how to view the last one from the command line.

I've installed the AWS and ASK CLI already and am able to view Cloudwatch logs, but there is not a fast way of view the last ones.

Comment: Cloudwatch has a little delay. Some tools like "datadog" could help adding some organization, but you can't make it faster.

Comment: setting the log-type flag to Tail will allow you to get the logs right away in a base64 encoded string. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56814765/112233

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [aws logs describe-log-streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/describe-log-streams.html) to get the latest stream name and then [aws logs get-log-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/get-log-events.html) to get the log records themselves.

```
LOG_GROUP=/aws/lambda/[YOUR-LAMBDA-NAME]
LOG_STREAM=`aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP --max-items 1 --order-by LastEventTime --descending --query logStreams[].logStreamName --output text | head -n 1`
aws logs get-log-events --log-group-name $LOG_GROUP --log-stream-name $LOG_STREAM --query events[].message --output text
```

With latest AWS CLI you can also use tail.

```
aws logs tail $LOG_GROUP --follow
```

Answer (score 5):

If someone is still struggling and want to extract the latest log stream using AWS CLI

```
aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name '/aws/lambda/[YOUR_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME_GOES_HERE]' --query 'logStreams[*].logStreamName' --max-items 1 --order-by LastEventTime --descending
```

Or You want to query all logs stream of single lambda you can use

```
aws logs describe-log-streams --log-group-name '/aws/lambda/[YOUR_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME_GOES_HERE]' --query 'logStreams[*].logStreamName'
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the log-type flag you'll be able to get the cloudwatch logs from the execution. For example:

```
LOG_RESULT=$(aws lambda invoke --function-name arn:aws:lambda:REGION:111122223333:function:YOUR_LAMBDA_NAME --log-type Tail outfile --query LogResult --output text)

echo $LOG_RESULT | base64 -D
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
START RequestId: 3ab54034-ed40-4fd7-b660-17db96a25f59 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 3ab54034-ed40-4fd7-b660-17db96a25f59
REPORT RequestId: 3ab54034-ed40-4fd7-b660-17db96a25f59  Duration: 71.48 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 74 MB
```

This assumes that the function is executed synchronously however with `eventType` `RequestResponse`.

If you still need the actual CloudWatch log from there you can query based on the request id.

```
REQUEST_ID=$(echo $LOG_RESULT | base64 -D | grep START | cut -d " " -f 3)
aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name /aws/lambda/YOUR_LAMBDA_NAME --filter-pattern \"$REQUEST_ID\"
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "logStreamName": "2019/06/29/[$LATEST]f94a9c338ec445cda688c015b460621d",
            "timestamp": 1561775888037,
            "message": "START RequestId: 3ab54034-ed40-4fd7-b660-17db96a25f59 Version: $LATEST\n",
            "ingestionTime": 1561775888119,
            "eventId": "34828766136322027826299000340819150179641895561445048320"
        },
        {
            "logStreamName": "2019/06/29/[$LATEST]f94a9c338ec445cda688c015b460621d",
            "timestamp": 1561775888113,
            "message": "END RequestId: 3ab54034-ed40-4fd7-b660-17db96a25f59\n",
            "ingestionTime": 1561775903178,
            "eventId": "34828766138016884461387327717780753707358087734557278208"
        },
        {
            "logStreamName": "2019/06/29/[$LATEST]f94a9c338ec445cda688c015b460621d",
            "timestamp": 1561775888113,
            "message": "REPORT RequestId: 3ab54034-ed40-4fd7-b660-17db96a25f59\tDuration: 71.48 ms\tBilled Duration: 100 ms \tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 74 MB\t\n",
            "ingestionTime": 1561775903178,
            "eventId": "34828766138016884461387327717780753707358087734557278209"
        }
    ],
    "searchedLogStreams": [
        {
            "logStreamName": "2019/06/29/[$LATEST]f94a9c338ec445cda688c015b460621d",
            "searchedCompletely": true
        }
    ]
}
```

However, this output is not in order and includes the information about the log stream itself and which log groups were searched.

You can filter it using this command then:

`aws logs filter-log-events --log-group-name /aws/lambda/YOUR_LAMBDA_NAME --filter-pattern \"$REQUEST_ID\" --query 'sort_by(events, &timestamp)[*].[message]' | jq .[][0]`

**OUTPUT**:

```
"START RequestId: 610dcebf-bb7b-4c39-895b-8989b46386a8 Version: $LATEST\n"
"END RequestId: 610dcebf-bb7b-4c39-895b-8989b46386a8\n"
"REPORT RequestId: 610dcebf-bb7b-4c39-895b-8989b46386a8\tDuration: 154.04 ms\tBilled Duration: 200 ms \tMemory Size: 128 MB\tMax Memory Used: 73 MB\t\n"
```

Comment: `base64 -D` didn't work for me on mac but `base64 -Dd` did (`--decode` also works)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of useful open source tools than can help:

- [jorgebastida/awslogs](https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs)
- [TylerBrock/saw](https://github.com/TylerBrock/saw)